# How to input negative numbers in react ag-grid in numeric field type cells

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

i have react ag-grid which has data containing columns with definitions having numeric-field type. While editing these cells I am able to input only positive numbers and then it allows (-) to input but it does not parse it. so even i enter "-2" it  simply parses it to 2. It is not parsing negative values.

in the onCellValueChange method the value i get while entering "-2" is 2 as it is parsing to positive number.

How to input -ve numbers (Integers) in the grid?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

adding the char - on Property allowedCharPattern: '\d\.\,\-', on column filterParams, fixed the issue